# Django FormModel fields not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Currently, the template is only generating the Submit button without any input fields.
Also, if I change fields = "**all**" to fields= ["email","name"] it tells me that these fields do not exist.

**Model:**

```
class NewsletterSubscriber(models.Model):
    email = EmailField(required=True, label='Email')
    name = CharField(required=True, label='Name')
```

**Serializer:**

```
class SubscribeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsletterSubscriber
        fields = "__all__"
```

**View:**

```
def subscribe(request):
    form = SubscribeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubscribeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # redirect to a success page
    return render(request, 'subscribe.html', {'subscribeForm': form})
```

**Template:**

```
<form action="{% url 'subscribe' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ subscribeForm.as_p  }}
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

Comment: Share error traceback also pls!

Comment: No error when using __all__. When explicitly mentioning the fields I get: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (email, name) specified for NewsletterSubscriber

Comment: please share your project directory structure

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala not sure how to do that and what you want me to show you. If it helps I just created a test field in SubscribeForm which was successfully rendered in the template. So the problem lies somewhere in the link between the model and the modelform. In my "forms.py" I do from "DogShelter.web.models import NewsletterSubscriber".

Comment: plz update only form.py code screenshot link in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Wrong:

```
class NewsletterSubscriber(models.Model):
    email = EmailField(required=True, label='Email')
    name = CharField(required=True, label='Name')
```

Correct:

```
class NewsletterSubscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(required=True, label='Email')
    name = models.CharField(required=True, label='Name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
class NewsletterSubscriber(models.Model):
    email = EmailField(required=True)
    name = CharField(required=True)
```

```
class SubscribeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsletterSubscriber
        fields = ['email', 'name']
        labels = {'email': 'Email', 'name': 'Name'}
```

Instead of `fields` you could instead also go for `exclude` which would then obviously list the fields that you do not want to show up.

All these attributes you can put in the `Meta` class: [Modelformfactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory)

Comment: No, I still get the same mistake: raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (name, email) specified for NewsletterSubscriber